# TypeScript build error when assigning double dimensional array in VS2015

Tags: angular, multidimensional-array, typescript

I am getting build errors in typescript project in VS2015. The application works fine in browser, but now I cannot publish due to these build errors.

`export var AddedFields: Array<Array<Field>[]>[];`

`myGlobals.AddedFields[1][1] = new Field(newField.id, newField.label, newField.type, 0, 0);`

Error is

Error   TS2322  Build:**Type 'Field' is not assignable to type 'Field[][]'**.   \Projects\angular2-systemjs-dotnet-core-master\src\TestAngular2\wwwroot\app\components\form-layout.component.ts 40  Build

Could someone please identify what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the `Array` and `[]` notations can indeed be used to define an array type in Typescript, but by using both at the same time, you have effectively declared a 4-dimensional array.

If you stick to one type of notation, it should be, for the `Array` notation:

```
export var AddedFields: Array<Array<Field>>;
```

or for the `[]` notation:

```
export var AddedFields: Field[][];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
export var AddedFields: Array<Array<Field>[]>[];
```

What you have here is not an array of arrays.
It's an array of arrays of arrays of arrrays of arrays (probably).

You probably need just

```
export var AddedFields: Array<Array<Field>>;
```

Comment: Thank you @toskv :)